# How do you favor one package if both packages share the same module name?

Tags: python, import, namespaces, python-module

So two packages have the same module name, docopt and docopt-ng both export `docopt` - when there is a dependency, e.g.

```sh
pipenv install pip-upgrader docopt-ng
```

When you attempt to import

```py
import docopt
```

You get one of the two, but not the one I want today. Is there a trick to get the importer to import the other module (the one in docopt-ng)?

Things that didn't work:

```
$ python -c "from docopt-ng import docopt; print(docopt.__file__)"

  File "<string>", line 1
    from docopt-ng import docopt; print(docopt.__file__)
```

In .NET this is solved with [four-part names](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/assembly-in-net/).

Comment: have you tried `from docopt-ng import docopt`?

Comment: Where are the two packages installed? Since the import name corresponds to the directory name, they can't be in the same parent directory.

Comment: Is there a reason you need them both in the same project? I see you are already using `pipenv`, I'd keep the two versions separate if possible.

Comment: Conflicting transitive dependencies. Not all things are pipx installable.

Comment: @DickFox, I think the point is that OP wants to use `pip-upgrader`, which depends on `docopt`. But OP wants to use `docopt-ng` as a direct dependency.

Comment: @chris bingo, exactly what I meant to say.

Comment: I believe they both install a `docopt.py` in `site-packages` so one will overwrite the other. This is an installation issue so there is no way to import both. You may consider forking `jazzband/docopt-ng` and modify the setup process, then install your own fork using `pipenv` from git.

Comment: @about14sheep That is not a valid import because it contains a hyphen.

Comment: what @Seluck says but I'm wondering if there is a way to control the import order so that you end up with the version that you want in the `docopt.py` file (assuming it's always `docopt-ng`). then your dependencies will be happy and you will be happy. unless the dependency legitimately depends on something not in the fork... sounds bumpy

Comment: I looked at `__import__()` but that function doesn't seem to take a file system path, I wonder if there is an alternate that does

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it.

1. Use the `--target` flag to specify a location to install the docopt-ng version to a location that doesn't conflict with the other package.
2. Add that location to your `PYTHONPATH` env variable ahead of your normal packages directory.

```
(docopt) % pip install pip-upgrader
(docopt) % mkdir shims
(docopt) % pip install --target /Users/dickfox/docopt/shims docopt-ng
(docopt) % export PYTHONPATH='/Users/dickfox/docopt/shims'
(docopt) % python
>>> import docopt
>>> docopt.__file__ 
'/Users/dickfox/docopt/shims/docopt.py'
```

To use the original version:

```
(docopt) % python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/dickfox/docopt/shims', ETC...]
>>> del sys.path[1]
>>> import docopt
>>> docopt.__file__
'/Users/dickfox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docopt.py'
```

It didn't work for me to insert the special install location using `sys.path.insert` once I had already started python. I had to use the env variable.